# How to delete sentence with one word in Python

Tags: python, numpy, text, nltk

I'm currently working in one dataset that contains more than 10000+ news and I want to delete the sentences that contain only one word. I have searched about nltk and textcleaner, however I wasn't able to delete the sentences that contain only one word.

For example let say:
Input: **I want to delete sentence with one word. Okay. Fine.Let's do it.** 
Output: **I want to delete sentence with one word. Let's do it.**

The code is:

```
import textcleaner as tc
import nltk
import numpy as np

datafile = np.genfromtxt("f12filtered.txt", encoding='utf-8', delimiter=".")

data = tc.document(datafile)
data.remove_stpwrds()
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Your code only reads the file and removes stopwords. What have you done to solve the problem? Please add the code.

Comment: Deleting stop words was what I wanted to achieve. Read the description. However, it doesn't print out or print to txt file.

Comment: Actually you are right. Stop words don't delete the sentences with one word, it just deletes the most common used words in English. I couldn't find out how to delete sentence with one word. Any kinds of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data can be split into a list of sentences using delimiter '.'.And then if there is only one word in a sentence, we can delete that sentence. Data would be a list now and you can join the list if you want to work with complete text or else use it as it is. You can do this using the following code:

```
    data = data.split('.')
    for sent in data:
        sent = sent.split(' ')
        if len(sent) < 2:
            data.remove((' ').join(sent))
```

To join data to form a single string:

```
    data = ('.').join(data)
```

Comment: there are few errors, can you please fix them. one of them being `split(.)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I also include `data = tc.document(datafile)
data.remove_stpwrds()` with your code?

Comment: You can add it according to your use case. If you want redundant words to be removed, then use text cleaning and removing stop words along with the code that I have given.

Comment: I have added several lines myself, and it works perfectly. Thanks, lady. I accept your answer.